# SQL Server - How to validate number using regex?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have encountered a problem with regex in SQL Server.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE '/test/url/1' LIKE '/test/url/%[0-9]'
```

but there is a problem in this regex.

When I enter a non-valid URL like `/test/url/1w1`, it returns 1 and regex does not work correctly.

I want to validate an integer in URL with any length as `:ID` parameter.

Please recommend a correct regex for this situation.

Comment: sql-server weak for regex.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2017 14.0.1000.169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE '/test/url/1' LIKE '/test/url/%[0-9]' AND
      '/test/url/1' NOT LIKE '/test/url/%[^0-9]%'
```

This requires an integer (0-9) at the beginning of the last path-segment but avoids that the segment ends with an integer.

Comment: This is not a valid SQL expression.  Why was it accepted as the answer (and upvoted)?

Comment: I am not sure Gordon. David edited this last and My answer was just "NOT LIKE '/test/url/%[^0-9]%'".  Maybe the answer was accepted and upvoted before edit? Are you pointing out the missing 'And' condition here??

Comment: here is the reference to regex in SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-2017